# Moving a TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I need to move a `TabControl` dynamically in code. How do I do it?

I tried setting the margin, wrapping it in a scatterviewitem (using Center, but it always returns 0,0 ), wrapping it in a canvas (in hope of using .Left and .Top) but they all didn't work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: did you set HorizontalAlignhment ( or vertical) to sth like stretch/left etc.? Did you set the margin as well? Check these.

Comment: I set the HorizonalAlignment to Middle and VerticalAlignment to Center. Therefore, the tabcontrol is in center-bottom of the screen. I need to make it "disappear" into the edge when I drag it down, so was thinking of doing the animation by setting the location... I tried setting the margin, but margin returns Left as 0 in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving a control in WPF visually is based on the panel you used. For example, you have to adjust rows and columns if you use Grid and Top, Left properties if you used Canvas.

But a good approach is to use transformations. Use `TranslateTransform` to move your elements. Since transformation will not affect the layout pass.

```
   <TabControl >
       <TabControl.RenderTransform>
           <TranslateTransform x:Name="translation"/>
       </TabControl.RenderTransform>
   </TabControl>
```

Adjust X and Y values in code,

```
translation.X = 200;
```

Comment: Thank you! But TranslateTransform returns 0 for both x and y, and not the actual location... is that the way it's supposed to be?

Comment: Ok got it. X and Y is the amount of pixels to move relative to the original starting position. Thanks!